# How do I save sent mails in Outlook 2010?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2010

How do I save sent mails in Outlook 2010, similar to how Gmail saves the whole conversation related to one subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a built-in way in Outlook 2010 settings like there was in 2003 or 2007 (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/change-where-sent-e-mail-messages-are-saved-HA010164216.aspx), but you can create an Outlook rule (client rule) to save a copy of Sent emails to your PST (as it gets deleted in Exchange server after a while...)

> First create a local PST folder under 'My Outlook Data File' (e.g.
>   "Sent_Backup")
>
> Then go to Rules ->   Manage Rules and Alerts ->
>
> New Rule ->
>
> Apply rule on messages I send (at the bottom) -> (Next -> Yes) ->
>
> Next (do not select any condition) -> (Next) ->
>
> Select Action "Move a copy to the specified folder" ->
>
> Select your new Sent item folder ("Sent_Backup") -> (OK) ->
>
> Next (do not select any condition) -> (Next) ->
>
> Enter Description and select 'Run this rule now' -> Finish.

You're safe!